# Getting nearest 5 places on android google map app on the basis of longitudes, latitudes stored in sqlite

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, android-sqlite

I want to ask about something tricky. Hoping there will be some solution for it. My Question is, "I have a number of places (longitudes & latitudes) stored in my android-sqlite-database, and I want to get the nearest five locations with small-clickable-icons when I use GPS service to get my location. 
Does this have some solution??

Description: I have saved some location's coordinates in my sqlite db. When I start the GPS service, it gives my current location. With this current location, I also want to get some **nearest locations** from the locations that have been stored in sqlite db by me. Can I do that with some method?

Comment: Can you clarify that a bit? To be honest, I did not understand what you try to do...

Comment: What distances are you working with? Below metre,metres kilometers?

Comment: within a city range would be 3-4 km or more......